# Python was not found error when runnig code

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, pip

After a few routine windows updates, I started getting this error when I was running python code in VSCode.

`Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.`

I got told to first check PATH and to untoggle Python in App Execution Aliasies. I figured that python was already added to the PATH (I had just checked the box when downloading) and that when I untoggle Python in App Execution Aliasies I get another error

`'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

So I'm essentially stuck between two different errors and a correct PATH and the only times when I can run a code is when I run it from the default Python IDE that comes in the download package.

Anyone know how to fix this?

PS. when I download Python from Windows Store, it works but I don't know how to use `pip` with it to install external packages.

Below is the pic of my PATH.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using `python` rather than `python3`? Did you try using `py`? "when I download Python from Windows Store, it works but I don't know how to use pip with it to install external packages." It is a normal Python installation, and `pip` works with it in the normal way. Just as with any other situation with multiple installations of Python, the way you make `pip` install to a specific installation is to *use that installation to run `pip`*.

Comment: Have you made any edits to your PATH? I think it looks fine as the Python 3.10 installation folder + Scripts are at the top. Restart VS Code (close all VS Code windows) and try again. Does the problem persist?

Comment: And the problem clearly is that when you "run your code in VSCode", you are invoking `python3`, and there is no `python3.exe` in your path (in the python installation folder(s)), before the nasty `WindowsApps` which has the (wrong) `python3.exe`

Comment: @np8 I get the ```'python3' is not recgnized...``` error only when I untoggle it in the App Execution Aliasies. https://imgur.com/Yq1sl8O  
How do I add ```python3``` to PATH? Also, to answer the above commnet, I havn;'t made any manual changes to PATH na di rebooted VSCode and I still get the ```Python was not found...``` error.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel what cmd command do I use to have pip work for a specific python installation though?

Comment: The same as how you choose the Python installation to use in order to run *any other Python script or module*. There is a bootstrap executable for `pip`, but it's also a standard library module. Pip will even show you the syntax in its errors and warnings sometimes: `python -m pip <additional arguments for pip>`. Where `python` should be replaced with a path to a specific Python if you need to specify it, or with `py` if the Python Launcher is configured to give the Python you want, etc.

Comment: @Bentuim, What you described is what you would expect. Python 3.10 on Windows does not come with `python3.exe` . There is no such thing. The `python.exe` in the Python 3.10 *is* python 3. Your problem is that you are trying to invoke `python3.exe` rather than `python.exe`; You should change how you're running the script.

Comment: @Bentium, You say that you're "running python code in VSCode". How exactly you do that? How did you tell VS Code to use the `python3` executable you're now trying to use?

Comment: @np8 Thanks a lot for helping! I manged to fix it by just copy-pasting ```python.exe``` and renaming it to ```python3.exe``` in the python package and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall python. When you install python, there will be a prompt in the lower left corner to **automatically add it to the environment variable**. Please check it.

At the same time, please select the correct **Python interpreter** in vscode.

You can refer to [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for more information.

Comment: I've purged python and reinstalled it also checking the box for it to be added to the envirenoment variable (and that's how it's been added to PATH, I never edited it manually) but it still hit the same ```Python was not found error```.

Comment: @Bentuim What's the result if you run `python` in the cmd in windows instead of running python code in vscode.